# Forwarding Mail Using Python With added new contents

Tags: python, email, smtplib, imaplib

After replacing headers like from,to,sub i am able to forward mail to another email address.
But how can I forward mail by adding more attachments and more text or html content.

As we see in the gmail, new contents should be displayed before the forwrded message content. Any idea on how could we achieve this?

Forwarded mail can be multipart or not.

But since we add new content it will be multipart

I have tried the code below

```
# open IMAP connection and fetch message with id msgid
# store message data in email_data
client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host,993)
client.login(user, passwd)
client.select('INBOX')
result, data = client.uid('fetch', msg_id, "(RFC822)")
client.close()
client.logout()

# create a Message instance from the email data
message = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])

# replace headers (could do other processing here)
message.replace_header("From", from_addr)
message.replace_header("To", to_addr)
message.replace_header("Subject", "Fwd:"+ message["Subject"].replace("FWD: ", "").replace("Fwd: ","" ))


# open authenticated SMTP connection and send message with
# specified envelope from and to addresses
smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_host, smtp_port)
smtp.login(user, passwd)
smtp.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, message.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Hi, Did you get the solution to this ?

Comment: @Ankur Sharma, Not yet

Comment: Any news about this. I am fiddling arround with this, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this using the `email` package, attaching the original email as a part:

```py
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.message import MIMEMessage
from email import message_from_bytes

raw_email = get_raw_email() # get the original email from wherever
original_email = message_from_bytes(raw_email)

part1 = MIMEText("This is new content")
part2 = MIMEMessage(original_email)

new_email = MIMEMultipart()
new_email['Subject'] = "My subject"
new_email['From'] = 'abc@xyz.com'
new_email['To'] = '123@456.com'
new_email.attach(part1)
new_email.attach(part2)
```